# HPE Prlliant DL380 G9 mv system from HBA mode to smart Array mode

Tags: hp-proliant

I have a functional test system on a Proliant DL380 G9.  The DL380 is currently in HBA mode, meaning HDD connected to it will bypass the internal smart Array P840.

I would like to test this system using the internal P840, but i do not want to recreate the whole system again.

currently, when i reboot into smart storage setting and enable the P840, i get a warning of loosing all data on existing HDD. is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, that for Gen 9, the P840ar does not support mixed mode (HBA and RAID at the same time).  So i have to change my system to RAID mode in order to use the P840ar.
Of course, that means i will loose all my data.

On related note, Gen10 controllers do support mixed mode.

In my case, since i was mostly interested in keeping my guest vm and the host, i was able to get away with recreating the host with the P840ar in RAID mode, then i rsync'd my vm's over from the old system.

Answer (score 0):

It's in "HBA" mode - meaning you're still using the P840. The traffic to the drives is still directed through that controller.

In HBA mode, you don't get the benefits of drive write cache (and obviously the benefits of the redundancy of RAID).

If you truly want to use the controller in a RAID configuration, the operation may not directly modify the data but there is a significant chance for data loss, even if you migrate the system from N drives in JBOD mode to N logical volumes in RAID-0.